# Can I override a spring bean definition defined using classpath scan?

Tags: java, spring, plugins

I have an application which has a very simple plugin architecture by the means of registering additional behaviour using spring classpath scanning ("Installing" the plugin happens by putting the plugin.jar on the classpath).

This works great for registering additional beans and it also works great for registering hooks like this:

```java
// core.jar:
@Component
class CoreClass {
  public void addListener(Listener listener) { /* ... */ }
}

// plugin.jar
@Component
class Plugin {
  public Plugin(CoreClass coreClass) {
    coreClass.addListener(new PluginListener());
  }
}
```

However sometimes it is more appropriate to to replace an entire bean. This might look like this:

```java
// core.jar:
@Component("someBean")
class CoreClass implements CoreInterface {
  @Override
  public void doStuff();
}

// plugin.jar
@Component("someBean")
@Order(HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE)
class Plugin implements CoreInterface {
  @Override
  public void doStuff();
}
```

In this case I want that both `Plugin` and `CoreClass` are discovered by classpath scan during startup, but then the `CoreClass`  should be ignored, because the bean `someBean` has another definition with higher precedence.

I am aware that I could do this using XML (`<import resource="classpath*:plugin-spring.xml" />`), because XML allows overriding definitions. But is this also possible using annotations?

Edit: Note that I sometimes have multiple bean instances of the same type (with different properties) which I inject name-based. Thus I actually need to override the bean with a certain name.

Answer (score 0):

Possible solution to use:

**@Primary**

Indicates that a bean should be given preference when multiple candidates are qualified to autowire a single-valued dependency. If exactly one 'primary' bean exists among the candidates, it will be the autowired value.

This annotation is semantically equivalent to the  element's primary attribute in Spring XML.

May be used on any class directly or indirectly annotated with @Component or on methods annotated with @Bean.

```
// core.jar:
@Component
class CoreClass implements CoreInterface {
  @Override
  public void doStuff();
}

// plugin.jar
@Component
@Primary
class Plugin implements CoreInterface {
  @Override
  public void doStuff();
}
```

http://memorynotfound.com/handling-multiple-autowire-candidates-with-spring-primary/

Or you could use :

```
@Configuration  
@ImportResource( { "classpath*:core-spring.xml", "classpath*:plugin-spring.xml" } )  
public class ConfigClass { }
```

I suspect that problem with annotations is not clear which order to override, if you define over notations same name you will end-up with `ConflictingBeanDefinitionException` spring will not allow you to have `@Component` or `@Bean` with same name. In xml you can manage override order that’s why you can do this over xml. In annotations you can't do that.

Any given **Spring context can only have one bean for any given id or name**. In the case of the XML id attribute, this is enforced by the schema validation. In the case of the name attribute, this is enforced by Spring's logic.

However, if a context is constructed from two different XML descriptor files, and an id is used by both files, then one will "override" the other. The exact behavior depends on the ordering of the files when they get loaded by the context.

So while it's possible, it's not recommended. It's error-prone and fragile, and you'll get no help from Spring if you change the ID of one but not the other.

However, if a context is constructed from two different XML descriptor files, and an id is used by both files, then one will "override" the other. The exact behavior depends on the ordering of the files when they get loaded by the context.

Comment: True, Primary works in the case you show above (type based injection). However in my case I oftentimes have multiple instances of a certain type which I inject name based. But @Primary does still not allow to define two beans with the same name.

Comment: I suspect that you are trying to do something what spring is not destined to do. My suggestion is use `@Primary` and where you need another bean use `@Qualifier`.